# GStreamer streaming has to start client first

Tags: streaming, gstreamer

I am able to stream h264 or MPEG4 video. Client (player) has to be started first and then start streaming (start server).

What I need is to be able to connect to the already playing stream (start client after server).

Both server and client run on same i.MX6 device.

Server example:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -vvv
  filesrc location=bruce.mp4 typefind=true \
  ! qtdemux name=demux \
  demux.video_00 \
  ! queue ! h264parse split-packetized=true \
  ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! gdppay \
  ! udpsink host=239.255.1.1 port=5004
```

Client example:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -vvv
  udpsrc port=5004 multicast-group=239.255.1.1 caps="application/x-gdp" \
  ! gdpdepay ! gstrtpjitterbuffer \
  ! rtpmp2tdepay ! mpegtsdemux name=demux \
  ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 \
  ! vpudec low-latency=true framedrop=true \
  ! mfw_isink sync=false
```